# Questionnaire - single item missing not at random

Tags: missing-data, multiple-imputation

I am planning an RCT where the primary outcome is a questionnaire score. The score is measured at baseline and follow-up and we are adjusting for the baseline value. We are planning with loss to follow-up of 10%, that is, 10% don't provide any questionnaire data at follow up but anticipate actually an even slightly lower drop-out of 5-8%.

The  problem I have is a single item on the questionnaire about participants sex life. Previous similar studies suggest that having an individual item missing is very rare (approx. 1%) apart from the question about sex life. This item is likely to be missing in about 10% of completed questionnaire at baseline and follow-up. Also, I think it's highly likely that this is MNAR because participants with a lower sex score are more likely to refuse to answer. How would you deal with this sort of missingness? Is a particular type of multiple imputation advised? Or would available data analysis be OK? I'm guessing mean score of the answered items would be an overestimate...

Many thanks for your help

Comment: You could start by regressing the sex score on the missingness of the question that you think may be MNAR.

Comment: Thanks for your reply Frans. Sorry, what I wrote was a bit unclear. There is no sex score just a questionnaire item about sex life (couldn't be worse to couldn't be better).  So I should have written that participants whose true answer would be towards the 'couldn't be worse' end are more likely to refuse to answer this question.